# Crystal report subreport very slow after database upgrade

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

We upgraded sql server database from 2000 to 2008. Crystal report with a subreport was taking around 50 seconds on 2000 database now same report is taking 3 minutes.
I don't have a clue what's  the problem?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

**Update usage counters**: In earlier versions of SQL Server, the values for the table and index row counts and page counts can become incorrect. To correct any invalid row or page counts, run `DBCC UPDATEUSAGE` on all databases following the upgrade from 2000 to 2008.

You should also rebuild your indexes (and ensure column statistics are updated).

Comment: Mitch Wheat - I have reubuild the indexes on the tables still no improvement.

Comment: Yes I ran DBCC UPDATEUSAGE on the upgraded database. Still same time, no improvements.

Comment: are the servers comparable in speed? DISK IO sub-system particularly?

Comment: Yes. all other apps and componenets on this new database are working fine except some crystal reports which has subreports. All those are slow 3-4 times comparted to sql 2000 database.